# Element not visible when I try to enter password in "Password"' textbox

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to place an order in an e-commerce page and I am able to locate elements for password successfully, but when I try to enter password, I am getting error as

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

**Note:** Sometimes it is working but sometimes it is throwing the above error.

Can someone provide a solution and why the test is throwing this error.

Here is the HTML code for the element

Here is the following code

```
             System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\AAA\\Desktop\\Softwares\\chromedriver.exe");
             WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
             driver.get("http://www.flipkart.com");
             //driver.manage().window().maximize();
             driver.findElement(By.className("LM6RPg")).sendKeys("Shirts");
             driver.findElement(By.className("vh79eN")).click();
             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='products']/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/a")).click();
             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fk-mainbody-id']/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/a/div/div")).click();
             //driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fk-mainbody-id']/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[5]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/span")).click();
             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fk-mainbody-id']/div/div[7]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[6]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/form/input[8]")).submit();
             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='fk-mainhead-id']/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/a/span[1]")).click();
             // driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("VIEW CART")).click();
             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='view-cart-form']/button")).click();

             driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("9840123453");
             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ng-app']/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form/input")).click();
             //WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
             //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("password")));

             driver.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("bbb181");
             driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ng-app']/div/div[2]/ul/li[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/form/input")).click();
```

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the website. Is the password element always visible on the page on the page or does it appear after performing the earlier actions?

Comment: you might want to anonimize those login information you got there

Comment: The password that we enter in password text box is encrypted like found in other password text box. The error is dispalying because the characters are not visible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You comment almost good solution. You wrote:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("password")));
```

Change the condition for:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("password")));
```

and this should work.

Comment: the wait also needs to be moved before driver.findElement(By.id("email"))